# Timepicker Dialog always AM/PM

Tags: java, android, timepickerdialog

I create two timepickerdialog in my app,
but I want one of my timepicker dialog can only show "AM",
and the other one can always show "PM",
How can I do?

This is my timepicker

http://ppt.cc/xGspr

Answer (score 0):

While I would not do as I will describe since it is not a good way, I do not think there is a better way than this one, and just to give at least one way, this can be achieved by iterating over the Views under `TimePicker` and comparing their `ResourceName`s to `android:id/am_label` and `android:id/pm_label`.

Wrote a method to set `TimePicker` to AM or PM, if `am` is `true`, sets to AM, and to PM otherwise.

```
private void setMidday(View v, boolean am) {
    if (!(v instanceof ViewGroup)) {
        System.out.println(v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId())); //You can check the resourcenames by this one
        if (am == true) { //disable PM set to AM
            if (v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()).equals("android:id/pm_label")) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()).equals("android:id/am_label")) {
                v.performClick();
                v.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
        else { //disable AM set to PM
            if (v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()).equals("android:id/pm_label")) {
                v.performClick();
                v.setClickable(false);
            }
            if (v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()).equals("android:id/am_label")) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        setMidday(child, am);
    }
}
```

Also removed the clickability of AM and PM labels after hiding the other one since it is meaningless to click already clicked one now.

You can use this method by first getting the first child of your `TimePicker` object and then call setMidday to set TimePicker to AM or PM.

```
View firstChild = timePicker.getChildAt(0);
setMidday(firstChild, true); //set it to AM and disable PM
//or
setMidday(firstChild, false); //set it to PM and disable AM
```

Setting TimePicker to PM[image: PM TimePicker]

Setting TimePicker to AM[image: AM TimePicker]